# Symfony3 - Make the logout path POST only

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm working on a Symfony 3 project - I'd like to make the logout path POST only and protect it using CSRF tokens, like you can do on other routes that use forms.

I can't see anything mentioned in the [Security Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#logout-configuration) - is this even possible? Or is there a way of implementing this with some custom logic? Is it possible to implement a custom controller/action for this?

Thanks!

Comment: the logout-path route must be defined somewhere ... then it depends on the way in which it is defined. for example for annotations it would be `@Method("POST")`. however, you probably have to find your route first.